# Run Junit Test via command line

Tags: java, command-line, junit

Hi first i have already search and saw many post on that on stack overflow and other forum but i can't find any solution X(
I would launch a Junit test on command line and without maven 
first my work folder

```
->JunitTest
-->.classpath
-->lib
---->hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
---->junit-4.12.jar
-->src
---->sommeClass 
-------->Somme.java (class to test)
---->TestSommeClass
-------->SommeTest.java (class test)
```

I tried the following command : java -cp lib/junit-4.12.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestSommeClass.SommeTest

But i have the following error : initializationError(org.junit.runner.JunitCommandLineParseResult)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [TestSommeClass.SommeTest]

I'm pretty sure that is a problem with my classpath but i tried the SET CLASSPATH command but nothing append in my .classpath file
Here my classpath file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/cta-junit-runner-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/cta-junit-runner-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/junit-4.12.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

I'm begin with Junit, my test work perfectly in Eclipse and i realy don't find solution to my problem since more than 2 days so please any help would be great ! ^^

Comment: use a build tool instead of eclipse (gradle, maven, ...)

Comment: you're missing the *src* folder in the path

Comment: i don't know what you mean src is the first line in the file does is it wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is: when you start a JVM on the command line, you use -cp to tell it about where to find ALL the classes you will later need. As of now, the classpath that you give to the JVM **only** contains the JUnit JAR.

So how do you think that JVM would be able to load the class under test for example? In other words: everything in your xml snippets that translates to a location where .class files are taking from ... needs to be on your -cp information as well.

Of course, your question doesn't tell us where we would find the compiled classes of your "production" code.

Comment: Don't. I am using Junit for years by now; but I guess if I would be asked to run tests manually outside of eclipse and outside of our "backend" built system; it would take me quite some time to get there, too.

Comment: so the command should look like more java -cp "Junit Path";"hamcrest-core path";"compiled class to test";"compiled class test" org.junit.runner.JunitCore TestSommesClass.SommeTest ? but if i need to give all class path after -cp what's the utility define a file class path ?

Comment: You figured one of the reasons why people typically use eclipse or a build system to run unit tests. Because it is cumbersome to do it manually. The only thing that you can do is to start writing up little scripts; that for example setup env variables. In other words: you willingly decided to take the long and hard route. Now, you are facing what that actually means ;-)